# Intuitive Explanation for Gradients in ReLU-Activated Networks

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

When calculating gradients for backpropagation, a surprising result is that the gradient of the weights in a ReLU-activated layer ends up being a diagonal matrix. I am seeking to understand how this makes sense intuitively, in terms of gradient descent.

Does this mean that weights in the non-diagonal positions don't have an impact on the loss? How could that be? Do these weights never get updated at all?

Comment: Think of what what's a gradient of the linear activation

Answer (score 0):

> a surprising result is that the gradient of the weights in a ReLU-activated layer ends up being a diagonal matrix

Well, it doesn't. You just initialized your weights with a diagonal matrix.